# How to use phaser documention?

Tags: phaser, documentation

im new to game development and i began with phaser which seems to be a great framework but i can't understand it's documention very well.
Lets talk about phaser groups [docs](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Group.html) [examples](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/groups)

How you understand how to use groups based on the documention ? Examples are clearer but limited they dont cover everything.

---

PS: valueerror answered this question in [html5gamedevs](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/)

[link](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/13139-how-to-use-phaser-documention/) to answer

Comment: Maybe if you could ask a more specific question we could be of more assistance. Documentation is a bit of a pain when starting out on any platform, but Phaser is pretty well off and has a healthy group of users, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a basic understanding of Phaser as well, but I know how to use the docs. The classes will be the classes in the `Phaser.Game` module. You make an instance of that at the start of your game. This is an example from my Flappy Bird game:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(790, 400, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', stateActions);
```

I access the classes by `game.class`. The documentation tells you what the class contains and the methods  and what they do with their parameters. Hope this helps!